# Android kitkat "ok google" function, disabled after enable the notification accessibility of any app

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, accessibilityservice

I recently developed an application run on android that monitors the notifications received with a service. When i enable the accessibility to monitor the notification the "ok google" always on function is disabled.

The code is based on this: https://github.com/Snirpo/whatsapprelay

You can reproduce the error installing : Pebble Whatsapp

Enable the application in the menu accessibility in settings:

"Pebble WhatsApp notifier needs to:

- Observe your acions
  receive notifications when you're interacting with an app."

**when i turn on this function, the always on "ok google" is automatically disabled.**

i'm running KitKat on a Nexus5

**does anyone know why? and how i can solve?**﻿

Comment: This repository has been removed. Do you have a copy of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In whatsapprelay/blob/master/src/com/snirpoapps/whatsapprelay/WhatsAppService change this:

```
info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK
```

To this:

```
info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC
```

Comment: Also an issue for type FEEDBACK_SPOKEN.

Comment: Also found this issue in Jelly Bean.